# Windows 10 Domain User is automatically made a local administrator

Tags: windows-10, administrator, active-directory, group-policy, standard-user

We have a Windows 2012 AD domain.

We have added some new Windows 10 Pro systems to our domain and are having an issue where when a domain user (non-admin) logs into the machine, they are automatically made a local administrator.  Their account does not show up in the local Administrators group nor is there a place where we can see the user when logged in as an admin to be able to change them to a standard user.

The machines have been joined to the domain while logged in as a local admin and using the credentials of a domain admin.  The first time the credentials of the domain user are used is when their account logs in for the first time after the machine was already a member of the domain.

Any ideas?

This is what it looks like when you go to settings while logged in as the user (last name and domain blacked out):

[image]

Comment: Are there other domain groups that are members of local admins? Is the user a member of one of those domain groups?

Comment: The Local administrators group only contains 3 local accounts and the Domain Admins AD group of which the domain user is not a member of.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what the problem was.

We have a Remote Desktop Users Group that was (yikes!) added to the Domain Admins group and this caused the user to have admin rights on the machine.  Luckily it was for only a short period of time and no damage was done.

Comment: Good thing to audit, and it's a good idea to audit that whole group.